# select option update db from linking

Tags: php, database, hyperlink, html-select

How to update the database from select option.

if test is selected update the users id from db row.

```
<form action="action.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id'] ?>" method="post">
<select name="op">
<option value="test">test</option>
<option value="test2">test2</option>
</select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if ($_POST['op'] == "test") 
{ 
$sql = "UPDATE * from users SET increment = increment + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
mysql_query($sql); 
}
else 
{ 
echo "test2 is selected can't update the db"; 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `UPDATE users` instead of `UPDATE * from users`

Comment: **Heads up!** The next major release of PHP is *deprecating* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

Learn MySQL Basics from [**Here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-data-manipulation.html).

And Change:

```
$sql = "UPDATE * from users SET increment = increment + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET increment = increment + 1 WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: it's not updating the db row, form action link is userid exp: action="action.php?id=<?php echo $dn2['userid']?>"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about retrieving primary key `id` which you are sending from  action attribute via get method. Update your query to

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET increment = increment + 1 WHERE id = '".$_REQUEST['id']."'";
```